# Google Maps: Keep additional info with LatLng while dragging polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my JavaScript application, I am trying to edit my paths which are stored in database. To achieve that, I create a `google.maps.Polyline` with array of `google.maps.LatLng`. For each `LatLng` I add id of row stored in database simply as:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
latLng.id = id;
coords.push(latLng);
```

The result is similar as here:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polyline-simple_editingEvents.html

This is working and I can access the id. However once the point is dragged, new `LatLng` is created and the old one is dropped – and so the original id is lost. How can I keep the id with each point to be able to update the row in the database?

Comment: Can you use it's index in the array?

Comment: Well once some points are added, the indexes gets out of sync with ids, that is probably not the best way to go :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when a point has been dragged the `set_at`-event of the path fires. The callback of the `set_at`-event receives 2 arguments:

1. the  index of the updated item in the path
2. the previous item before the update

Based on these arguments it's easy to set the id-property of the new  item to the id-property of the previous item:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath.getPath(),"set_at",function(i,o){          
       this.getAt(i).id = o.id;
    });
```

Demo:  [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QLBt4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QLBt4/)